# t-SQL IF...ELSE and more than one value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have problem with two queries:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE pracownik_zamowienie (@id int)

AS

IF (SELECT EmployeeID FROM Orders WHERE EmployeeID LIKE @id) LIKE @id
BEGIN
    SELECT OrderID FROM Orders
    END

    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SELECT OrderID, EmployeeID FROM Orders
        END
```

And this one:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dwa_produkty1 (@id1 int, @id2 int) AS

IF (SELECT OrderID FROM [Order Details] WHERE ProductID LIKE @id1) LIKE (SELECT OrderID FROM [Order Details] WHERE ProductID LIKE @id2)
BEGIN
    SELECT OrderID FROM [Order Details]
END
```

In first I want to get orderID's for employee which ID I type myself, but it doesnt work. When I type ID which is not in database, the query returns proper answer.

In second query I want to get answer which should be list of OrderID's, which contains two different ProductID's.

Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Using a LIKE operator with an integer parameter seems a little odd.  You should probably be doing EmployeeID = @id instead.

Comment: unfortunatelly it doesnt work too.

Comment: A couple of suggestions:  create a separate SO post for each sp/question...  For SP#1, change the name of the input parameter--it's not clear to me if it refers to an employee id, order id, etc....Also for SP#1, you have 2 possible return sets and they don't have matching columns.  What happens if your application tries to reference a column in the return set that doesn't exist?

Comment: why would you have two different possible column list from one SP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will answer your first question

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT EmployeeID FROM Orders WHERE EmployeeID =@id)
BEGIN
    SELECT OrderID FROM Orders WHERE EmployeeID =@id
END

ELSE
    BEGIN
       SELECT OrderID, EmployeeID FROM Orders
    END
```

Second query should be something like this:

```
SELECT OrderID FROM where ProductID IN (@id1, @id2)
```

Comment: @Piotr - you need to let us know  - works or does not.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for late answer, I was AFK for 2 days ;)